# SSD partition table gets destroyed when I unplug it

Tags: partitioning, ssd

I just bought my first SSD an hour ago, thought it was first hand, but I saw the box was open and there were files inside the SSD when I plugged it in to move my files over to the new drive.

Turns out, I did a couple of tests, SMART reports the disk is healthy. I created a new partition, unplugged, replugged it, and voila, the disk didn't show up. Went to gparted on linux to find I had no partition table. Created an msdos partition table and a fat32 partition, unplugged and replugged, and they were gone. Tested that about 3 times, no luck. I also tried with a gpt partition table, but I wasn't lucky either.

SMART output:

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     KINGSTON SUV400S37120G
Serial Number:    50026B776502282E
LU WWN Device Id: 0 550380 440010000
Firmware Version: 0C3FD6SD
User Capacity:    120.034.123.776 bytes [120 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      M.2
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   Unknown(0x0ffe), ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 1.5 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Fri Jul 29 17:44:32 2016 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    5) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x71) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   0) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 48
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       6
100 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       12384
101 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       23648
170 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
171 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
174 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       9
175 Program_Fail_Count_Chip 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
176 Erase_Fail_Count_Chip   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       7
178 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Chip  0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
180 Unused_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot 0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       710
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0033   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   040   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       40 (Min/Max 23/40)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
201 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
204 Soft_ECC_Correction     0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
231 Temperature_Celsius     0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
233 Media_Wearout_Indicator 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       8
234 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       7
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       8
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3
250 Read_Error_Retry_Rate   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 0
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 0
Warning: ATA Specification requires self-test log structure revision number = 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 0
Note: revision number not 1 implies that no selective self-test has ever been run
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

I may be doing something wrong, but if I'm doing so, I gotta relearn how disks work. Thank you very much.

Comment: You did “remote safely”, right?

Comment: @Daniel B I unmounted the drive, yes. Even if I hadn't there is no reason why a partition table would disappear.

Comment: Unmounting is not necessarily enough. Please try again with turning off the PC completely.

Comment: I did turn off the PC completely to try install Ubuntu, and the installer did hold. But that doesn't mean anything, I copied the data using dd which copies it raw

Comment: Your drive may be faulty. If files that the SSD had prior to you formatting it were not "preloaded software" installers, you may have recieved a used SSD. Try running tests. Also try another cable and another motherboard SATA port.

Comment: @JackWhite seems it was the cable I was using. Since i plugged it in an SATA port, it works fine. Cable may be faulty, but I doubt it. And files were not preloaded, so the drive was used. SMART says it's almost brand new though. 100% lifetime left and all that

Comment: SMART shows that the drive was turned on for less then two hours and only turned off and on just 6 times, but SMART information may be resettable through low-level utilities. SATA cables can in fact be bad - it happened to me once or twice. Posting as an answer. If there are no problems in a few days - new cable probably fixed it (you may then want to accept my answer or write and accept your own). Otherwise, please comment. You should still ask SSD seller why were there rogue files on your device.

Comment: You could also run a benchmark and compare the results with those in your SSD's description. For example, crystal disk info can be used to benchmark disks: http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html

Comment: You are welcome. Hope it the problem is resolved completely. If SSD starts failing again, post a new question with full specs of your motherboard, SSD, relevant syslog entries, and new SMART results. Anyway, I still suggest running a benchmark and comparing the results with what is expected of the ssd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SATA cable or port may be faulty.

Try using another cable and plugging into a different motherboard SATA port.

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer has already been selected, but I think it's worth adding that for similar issues, with partition tables getting corrupted and/or SSDs not being detected, the problem could also be trying to use SATA configured in "IDE mode" in the BIOS. When using SSDs, SATA should be set to "AHCI mode" (or "Combined Mode", but that's more complicated and I haven't investigated it; reportedly it only sets *some* of the available ports to AHCI). See also here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/558459/cannot-create-partition-table-on-ssd